# Unbounmded status from Cplex.getStatus();

Tags: cplex

I am writing a MILP using Cplex, the status return code is "unbounded".
How can I debug this or figure out why it is unbounded?

Answer (score 0):

with Erwin's hint , I figured it out that  I did not write some bound constraints correctly!﻿

The trick which Erwin gave is we can use:

```
 Add a bound to the objective:
 MAX Z
 Z <= 1e7
 ...
 and inspect the solution for large numbers.﻿
```